What makes you think you are a true Christian?
I feel like many people have their own definition for what it means to be a Christian. To each person who sees this, do you believe you are a Christian? Why? What does it mean for you personally to be a Christian?
Thank you!

Oh, I would rephrase this question If I were you. This might be an opinionated question, meaning a question that asks for opinions. Also, questions should focus on a specific denomination or compare denominations. Do you want an overview of "all" denominations as to what a Christian is/how one becomes a Christian? Or are you interested in a specific denomination?

This definitely needs to be scoped towards a particular group of self-identifying 'Christians'. There is a broad spectrum of opinion on this very subject. From what group would you wish to receive a definitive answer ? Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site and in particular that questions which may be answered from multiple viewpoints must needs be scoped to one in particular or must ask for an 'overview' (an enormous task) of all possible alternatives.

@NigelJ I proposed an edit that takes the overview over all denominations direction. An enormous task indeed but I think still a nice one for those searching.

'To each person who sees this' . . . . .  so you are calling for all who read to write an answer ? But you have not given us your own testimony. (My testimony is available, freely - all twelve pages of it - on my website, for which, see my profile.)

@telion no one likes answering  overviews

I believe that I am a sinner: That I stand justly condemned before a holy God and that there is nothing that I can do to rectify my situation.
I believe that God has done what I cannot do through the death, burial, and resurrection of Jesus Christ to reconcile me to himself.
I believe that I cannot add to it or take away from it and that the only safe ground is to trust that he has removed my sin as far away as the East is from the West.
I believe that he has put his holy spirit in me to guide me into all truth and to conform me to the image of the Son that he loves.
That is my sole touchstone.  I trust Him to accomplish in me what he has said he will accomplish despite my weakness and my failings.
Everything else is what I am responsible to think, say, and do in response.  Denominational allegiance can either help or hinder.  Theological allegiance can either help or hinder.
God is true and the word of the Lord stands forever.  That is my only hope.

Ditto on that for me. +1
